# How can I sort List<Object> CRUD Repository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, crud

I'm trying to build simple REST for purchases I need 2 methods. The first method should show all purchases sorted by date. The second one removes all purchases for specified date I made a method to add and to get all purchases. Now I'm stuck.

```
@Entity
@Table (name="purchase")
public class Purchase {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="createat")
private Date created;

@Column(name="price")
private BigDecimal price;


@Column(name="currency")
private String currency;
@Repository
public interface PurchaseRepository extends JpaRepository<Purchase, Long> 
{
}

@Service
public class PurchaseService {

@Autowired
private PurchaseRepository purchaseRepository;

public void addPurchase(Purchase purchase) {
    purchaseRepository.save(purchase);
}

public List<Purchase> getAllPurchase() {

    List<Purchase> purchase = new ArrayList<>();
    purchaseRepository.findAll().forEach(purchase::add);
    return purchase;
}
}

@RestController
public class PurchaseController {

@Autowired
private PurchaseService purchaseService;

@PostMapping("/purchase")
public void addPurchase(@RequestBody Purchase purchase) {
    purchaseService.addPurchase(purchase);
}

@RequestMapping("/purchase")
public List<Purchase> getAllTopics() {
    return purchaseService.getAllPurchase();
}
}
```

What I need:
1. method to sort my List sorted by date 
2. method that removes all purchases for specified date

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Data JPA features in these cases.

Add the following methods to PurchaseRepository:

1. `List<Purchase> findAllByOrderByCreatedAsc();`
2. `long deleteByCreated(Date created);`

And after all, Spring is going to generate an appropriate query based on a method name.

Comment: Thank you, now the 1-st method is working! unfortunately I can't get how to implement the secondone, I mean how to make my controller work

Comment: Accept answer If you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
long deleteByCreated(Date date);
@Transactional
public long deleteAllByDate(Date date){
    return purchaseRepository.deleteByCreated(date);
}
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/purchasess/{date}")
    public long findAllByCreatedBetween(@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") 
@PathVariable  Date date){
        return purchaseService.deleteAllByDate(date);
    }
```